# nsight eclipse edition profiling nvprof

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nsight

I work on Ubuntu 10.04 and I develop in CUDA on nsight eclipse edition 5.0.0.

I have to use nsight eclipse edition to make a profiling of my code with nvprof. I can launch nvprof in the terminal to profile my code but when I want to launch profiling in nsight, it switch to the profile perspective but send me this error message

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: unable to find nvprof
```

I put the folder in the PATH but it did not work. For the debugger, there is a box where you can put the link to the debugger launcher but I did not find the same for the profiler configuration.

If somebody use nsight eclipse edition to make profiling please help me because there is nothing on the web and I really need it.

I will be appreciated if you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi,
I found a solution. There is an executable file, nvvp in usr/local/cuda/bin. You have just to run nvvp in the terminal and it opens NVIDIA Visual Profiler. After that you have just to enter the file you want to profile (test.x) and the software runs and profiles your program.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try specifying path in the launcher script? CUDA 5.0 preview toolkit did not add path, this is how /usr/local/cuda/bin/nsight will look like in the upcoming toolkit realeases:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 /usr/local/cuda-5.0/libnsight/nsight
```

Make sure the script points to the proper toolkit install location.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Before applying this, it wasnt finding cuda.h and other headers.